# Why are my Airflow DAGs not running to completion?

Tags: airflow

I'm brand new to Airflow. I just installed it. I'm running the scheduler and the server. The database has been initiated. When I trigger a manual run of any of the example dags, they stay in the "Running" state indefinitely. You can see here that I started running at 22:03, and it's 22:06 - that's only 3 minutes, but this DAG should run in a matter of seconds. I've waited before for up to an hour an it never completes successfully.

Is this a common error someone can help me diagnose?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So .. it turns out that you need to have the DAG turned ON for it to run, even if you've scheduled it manually.